# Data is updated on Odoo 11 but not in its DB

Tags: php, odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-11

i have an strange situation on Odoo11 and i discover it because I'm doing an external system to extract the data from Odoo, so every time i update the data in odoo it looks ok on the Odoo System, but when i extract the data using PHP XMLRPC from product.product and product.template, data is not updated, however when i go to Odoo and review the data is there.

Example

In Odoo:
The item had a name "Product 1", and then I change to "Product One is the Best"

I see the information updated in Odoo, even when i exit and go in again

In PHP XML-RPC:

```
$models = new PhpXmlRpc\Client($server_url . "/xmlrpc/object");
    $c_msg = new PhpXmlRpc\Request('execute');
    $c_msg->addParam(new PhpXmlRpc\Value($dbname, "string"));
    $c_msg->addParam(new PhpXmlRpc\Value($uid, "int"));
    $c_msg->addParam(new PhpXmlRpc\Value($password, "string"));
    $c_msg->addParam(new PhpXmlRpc\Value("product.template", "string"));
    $c_msg->addParam(new PhpXmlRpc\Value("read", "string"));
    $field_list = array(
        new PhpXmlRpc\Value("id", "string"),
        new PhpXmlRpc\Value("name", "string"),        
    ); 
    $c_msg->addParam(new PhpXmlRpc\Value($field_list, "array"));
```

The name brings me "Product 1", even when i see it ok in Odoo system

I checked directly to the DB with the Odoo team and the info is not updated in DB, but the "write_date" and "__last_update" fields has the exact date and time of the last update when i changed the name.

Where can be the info being stored? Did anybody has the same situation as me???

Comment: This's not PHP problem, so you should check directly does Odoo do transactional/commit after it? I have Odoo 12 and I doesn't have your problem, we use NodeJS and PHP for it's CRM module.

Comment: Yeap, i Kow it's not a PHP problem, because we checked the Odoo DB and nothing is being saved there, however when you go to the Odoo System, all data is updated there like if is no problem, if is not saving the data in DB where can it be saved???